# Easter sunday in C++

Tags: c++, date

Is there any library that will help me to get date for easter sunday for given year in C++? I'm looking for something like `easter_date` or `easter_days` in PHP. It can be Linux only.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/easter.aspx

Comment: @Peter this sounds like homework, you might want to add that tag

Comment: @jimmcnamara no, it's business application where I need other parameters on holiday than on normal work day

Comment: @parapurarajkumar this works great, post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @PeterKrejci  Glad to be of help... Moved to answer section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [codeproject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/easter.aspx)

Comment: But does it have any easter eggs?

Answer (score 0):

Most PHP functions are actually implemented in C.

If you have an SVN client you can get the source code for the PHP easter_date and easter_days functions here:

https://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/ext/calendar/easter.c

I have no idea what the ethics of using this to create your own function is.

Comment: Cite the source if you use it to create your own function.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dateofeaster.com/ has an algorithm. It seems to match the PHP implementation.